# How to get curl response code in a variable along with output as a file, multiple outputs needs to be appended

Tags: bash, unix, curl, http-response-codes

I am trying to get the response code of the curl command to a variable and output of the same curl command in a file. Another curl command within a different function will run and the output should append to the same output file.

```
response=$(curl -i -H "content-type: application/json" -w "%{http_code}" -u "$id:$cred" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST http://sitename -d '{'<input>'}' >> out.txt
```

This is giving me neither the response nor the curl output in the file.
Below is working and  gives me response as the desired http code though.

```
response=$(curl -i -H "content-type: application/json" -w "{http_code}" -u "$id:$cred" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST http://sitename -d '{'<input>'}'
Echo $response
```

Comment: For better readability, please format your code lines by intending them by four spaces.

Comment: You need a percent sign `%{http_code}`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Yes, thank you for noticing it, I just missed it here, but it's present in the main code